# How to refresh a template page on Wordpress in 3 seconds - easiest method?

Tags: php, pages, templates, search, content

Basically, on my site I have content submitted via a search bar. I'm using a content-none template to detect if the user is signed in - and if so it submits a post programmatically (if the post doesn't exist)

Now, after this is done I'd like the page to refresh after 3 seconds, and since it will pick up the previous search term, it will go to the submitted post automatically.

Is there a PHP or Wordpress method of doing this? Or will I need to insert JavaScript into the template page? (or in theory - possibly a way of forwarding to the $post_id? though I don't know how to grab it via the search term or with the info from wp_insert_post... )

FYI I cannot get `header('refresh: 3;');` to work

Comment: Have you tried [wp_redirect()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)?

Answer (score -1):

Found a method!

`echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="3">' ;`

Comment: This is super annoying for your users, especially for those with assistive software.

Comment: yup - very bad UI practice. Consider the use of ajax to refresh your page content.